# Java code wont except next .nextLine(); scanner

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Caesar cipher for school but for some reason my code wont work. It doesn't error in decode either. The problem is after the scan.nextLine(); after it asks for a coded message to be entered the code just skips over the whole sequence and stops. Before I can enter anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;

public class CodeAssignment4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the key to your cipher");
    int key = scan.nextInt();
        if (key >= 26) {
            System.out.println("Key out of range");
            return; 
        }

System.out.println("Please enter your coded message");
    String codemessage = scan.nextLine();

int length = codemessage.length();

char[]codemessagearray = codemessage.toCharArray();

char value;

char newkey = (char)key;

String decodedmessage = " ";    

int i;
for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
    value = codemessagearray[i];

if ((value < 'a') || (value > 'z')) {
    System.out.println("Character out of range");
    break; 
}

value -= 'a'; //send range to zero
value -= newkey; //decrament key
value += 26; //account for negative
value = (char)((int)value%26);    

decodedmessage += value + 'a';    
}
if (i == length) {
    System.out.println(decodedmessage);
}

}
}
```

I think one of my breaks is causing a problem.

Comment: have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()` or create two `Scanner` object to avoid this.

It looks like the nextLine is consuming the input '\n' that was skipped by the `nextInt()` and stops. As `nextInt()`only scans the int values not the line separator.

For more info go to : [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)